# value passed to parent competent as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a value to parent compnent but I am getting object format instead of value. Here is my work

**Child component**

```
render() {
  return (
    this.props.data.map((val, idx) => {
      // do someting with val

      <Button onClick={this.props.action(0)}> pass to parent </Button>}
    )
  )
}
```

**Parent component**

```
action(val) {
  alert(val)
}

render() {
  return (
    <Child data={this.state.data} action={(val) => this.action(val)}
  )
}
```

I am expecting exact value such as `2` or`3` to be alerted but instead, I am getting object object alerted. What am I missing?

Console.log() result:

```
Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}altKey: (...)bubbles: (...)button: (...)buttons: (...)cancelable: (...)clientX: (...)clientY: (...)ctrlKey: (...)currentTarget: (...)defaultPrevented: (...)detail: (...)dispatchConfig: nulleventPhase: (...)getModifierState: (...)isDefaultPrevented: (...)isPropagationStopped: (...)isTrusted: (...)metaKey: (...)movementX: (...)movementY: (...)nativeEvent: (...)pageX: (...)pageY: (...)relatedTarget: (...)screenX: (...)screenY: (...)shiftKey: (...)target: (...)timeStamp: (...)type: (...)view: (...)_dispatchInstances: null_dispatchListeners: null_targetInst: nullpreventDefault: (...)stopPropagation: (...)get altKey: ƒ ()set altKey: ƒ (val)get bubbles: ƒ ()set bubbles: ƒ (val)get button: ƒ ()set button: ƒ (val)get buttons: ƒ ()set buttons: ƒ (val)get cancelable: ƒ ()set cancelable: ƒ (val)get clientX: ƒ ()set clientX: ƒ (val)get clientY: ƒ ()set clientY: ƒ (val)get ctrlKey: ƒ ()set ctrlKey: ƒ (val)get currentTarget: ƒ ()set currentTarget: ƒ (val)get defaultPrevented: ƒ ()set defaultPrevented: ƒ (val)get detail: ƒ ()set detail: ƒ (val)get eventPhase: ƒ ()set eventPhase: ƒ (val)get getModifierState: ƒ ()set getModifierState: ƒ (val)get isDefaultPrevented: ƒ ()set isDefaultPrevented: ƒ (val)get isPropagationStopped: ƒ ()set isPropagationStopped: ƒ (val)get isTrusted: ƒ ()set isTrusted: ƒ (val)get metaKey: ƒ ()set metaKey: ƒ (val)get movementX: ƒ ()set movementX: ƒ (val)get movementY: ƒ ()set movementY: ƒ (val)get nativeEvent: ƒ ()set nativeEvent: ƒ (val)get pageX: ƒ ()set pageX: ƒ (val)get pageY: ƒ ()set pageY: ƒ (val)get relatedTarget: ƒ ()set relatedTarget: ƒ (val)get screenX: ƒ ()set screenX: ƒ (val)get screenY: ƒ ()set screenY: ƒ (val)get shiftKey: ƒ ()set shiftKey: ƒ (val)get target: ƒ ()set target: ƒ (val)get timeStamp: ƒ ()set timeStamp: ƒ (val)get type: ƒ ()set type: ƒ (val)get view: ƒ ()set view: ƒ (val)get preventDefault: ƒ ()set preventDefault: ƒ (val)get stopPropagation: ƒ ()set stopPropagation: ƒ (val)__proto__: Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
onClick={() => this.props.action(val)}>
```

At the moment the function is being called on `render`, not on `click`.

Comment: Im still getting the same result `[object object]`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the callback instead of creating a new callback.
Should be:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.action(val)}> pass to parent </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to the above answer I would guess that `this.props.data` is an array of objects. In your map where you return the `Button` you need to access the property in the object which contains the value i.e. `onClick={() => this.props.action(val.value)}>`

also, this code uses a curly brace to open the function in the map and parens to close it:

```
    this.props.data.map((val, idx) => {
      // do someting with val
      <Button onClick={this.props.action(val.value)}> pass to parent </Button>
    )
```

If you are using braces then you need to add `return` before the `<Button />`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my code block. `val.value` won't work though, you need to look at `this.props.data` and find out what the property on the objects is called, can you log it out and paste it here?

Comment: You're passing the click event through instead of the val. This would happen  if you did this `onClick={(event) => this.props.action(event)}> `